# How to force displaying of int? value as string in Enity Framework object?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am not sure if it's the best formulated question but what I wanted to achieve is that I have 99% of object from database. In this example i use AnonymousList to just get a few columns from SQL and then convert it to Entity object.

I have expanded the object with property Size to be able to assign size of an object in database.

```
public partial class SzkolenieMaterialyPrzedmiotowe {
    public int? Size { get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Here's the code to get things going

```
 using (var context = new EntityBazaCRM(Settings.sqlDataConnectionDetailsCRM))
        {

            var anonimowaLista = context.SzkolenieMaterialyPrzedmiotowes.Where(d => d.SzkolenieID == szkolenieId).Select(d => new
            {
                d.MaterialyPrzedmiotoweID,
                d.MaterialyPrzedmiotoweTyp,
                Size = SqlFunctions.DataLength(d.MaterialyPrzedmiotowePlik),
                d.MaterialyPrzedmiotoweOpis
            }).AsEnumerable(); // anonymous list created to get only few columns

            var listaSzkolenieMaterialyPrzedmiotowe = anonimowaLista
            .Select(d => new SzkolenieMaterialyPrzedmiotowe
            {
                MaterialyPrzedmiotoweID = d.MaterialyPrzedmiotoweID,
                MaterialyPrzedmiotoweTyp = d.MaterialyPrzedmiotoweTyp,
                MaterialyPrzedmiotoweOpis = d.MaterialyPrzedmiotoweOpis,
                Size= d.Wielkosc,
            }).ToList(); // list based on anonymous list 

            objectListViewMaterialySzkoleniowe.SetObjects(listaSzkolenieMaterialyPrzedmiotowe);
        }
```

How can I force Size to actually display itself after conversion to KB (`Helpers.ConvertBytesToKilobytes(Size ?? 0);`) so it becomes a string with KB added after it so I can show it in ObjectListView instead of int value?

I tried doing it like that but that seems to fail..

```
public partial class SzkolenieMaterialyPrzedmiotowe {
    public int? Size{ get;
        set;
    }
    public string SizeToString
    {
        get
        {
            return Helpers.ConvertBytesToKilobytes(Size ?? 0);
        }
        set {
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: `public override ToString()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just convert the size property to a string and calculate the "XKb" inside your linq expression. However most people wouldn't want to lose the numerical byte value. If so just create another property or (static) method that will convert byte size to a string followed by units.

Doing a ToString() override as Valdislav suggested would work but it would be a bit confusing to override the entire ToString() functionality for the whole object just for a size conversion (imo). You could consider parametrizing the ToString to add more clarity and just call the base if no parameters are passed.

Here is a simple example as requested (and edited based on comments):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myDemo = new Demo();
        myDemo.Size = 1000000;
        myDemo.Value = 15.7m;

        Console.WriteLine("ToSizeInKb: " + myDemo.ToString(DemoConversionType.ToSizeInKb));
        Console.WriteLine("ToValue: " + myDemo.ToString(DemoConversionType.ToValue));
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Press enter to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines different ways to convert the Demo class objects into strings.
    /// </summary>
    enum DemoConversionType
    {
        ToSizeInKb,
        ToValue
    }

    class Demo
    {
        public int? Size { get; set; }
        public decimal Value { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Override the default ToString method and pass a "DemoConversionType"
        /// that defaults how the object should be converted to a string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// <param name='convType'></param>
        public string ToString(DemoConversionType convType)
        {
            switch (convType)
            {
                // Return the Size in Kb
                case DemoConversionType.ToSizeInKb:
                    return Size.GetValueOrDefault() / 1000 + "Kb";
                // Return the Value to 2 decimal places.
                case DemoConversionType.ToValue:
                    return string.Format("{0:N2}", Value);
                // Bad conv type, default back to the base ToString() method.
                default:
                    return base.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check my edit. I'v added the code i tried before posting but it won't work + I don't really know how to use it in anonymouse type and conversion type. In other words an example of what you are saying and how to use it would be nice :-)

Comment: @MadBoy Added some demo code that demonstrates one of the solutions mentioned.

Comment: How does it know that ToString() relates to Size.. what if I would have Size, ID, and some other fields and just one ToString() ? What if I wanted to have multiple choices like ToString for size is one thing ToString for ID is somethign else etc. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @MadBoy In my example I created an enum called ConversionType that's passed to the ToString method. So the caller has to pass: ConversionType.SizeInKb, that's how it knows. If you want a single ToString method you can add as many of these ConversionTypes as you want and then modify my switch statement to return the desired string value based on that type.

Comment: What I meant how I would proceed with having next to public int? Size { get; set; }  public decimal Value { get; set;} how I would have ToString() for Value as well (considering that I am having Size/ToString for size as well? Can you modify your example to show me this?

Comment: @MadBoy I've updated the example to show 2 different conversion types. One for "size as kb" and one for "value" (as a 2 digit decimal).